# Is it possible to pass current DataContext as ContructorParameter of ObjectDataProvider?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datacontext, objectdataprovider

It would be very useful to pass DataContext as parameter for DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ServiceDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type control:ServiceLayout}">
             <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                /*here could be DataContext..but how?*/
             </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter
               Content="{Binding
                    Source={StaticResource ServiceDataProvider}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I will use this DataTemplate in ListBox ItemTemplate. So, DataContext will be ListBoxItem bound object (type is known)

May be there are any other ways to pass parameter to constructor from DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Magnus (MM8)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/magnus%20(mm8)/?ws=usercard-mini) for the answer here: [Is it possible to pass current DataContext as ContructorParameter of ObjectDataProvider?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/382c6941-02d3-4c5c-8685-6d15bf996524/is-it-possible-to-pass-current-datacontext-as-contructorparameter-of-objectdataprovider?forum=wpf#382c6941-02d3-4c5c-8685-6d15bf996524)